# How do I implement resharper like camelhumps matching?

Tags: c#

How do I implement resharper like camelhumps matching?

I have made a start on it:

NOTE: this picture shows words seperated by spaces, but the algorithm I wrote would also work on camel humps by splitting words when they transition from lowercase to uppercase ( by adding a space ).  It would also work with underscores by replacing them with a space.

[image]

So far I have used a rating algorithm to determine the order of the matches.

But basically mine is limited to either complete match, match on first characters, or substring match.

I think resharper also allows funkier things than that, just wonder if there are any known useful algorithms for this kind of matching.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// This returns how good of a match something is using camelhumps.
   /// 0 = not a match
   /// 1 = exact match
   /// 2 = exact match no whitespace
   /// 3 = camel humps match on first character
   /// 4 = substring
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>
   private int GetMatchRanking( string value, string filter )
   {
      if ( filter.ToLower() == value.ToLower() ) return 1;
      if ( filter.RemoveAllWhitespace().ToLower() == value.RemoveAllWhitespace().ToLower() ) return 2;
      // Camel matching on first letters only: touch last changeset ==> tlc
      if ( filter.ToLower() == GetFirstLettersForFiltering( value ) ) return 3;
      if ( value.ToLower().Contains( filter.ToLower() ) ) return 4;
      return 0;
   }

   // Define other methods and classes here
   public List<string> CamelSplit( string s )
   {
      string text = Regex.Replace( s, @"([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2" );
      text = text.Replace( "_", " " ).Trim().ToLower();
      return text.Split( " ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList();
   }

   public string GetFirstLetters( List<string> strings )
   {
      return string.Join( "", strings.Select( s => s.Substring( 0, 1 ) ) );
   }

   public string GetFirstLettersForFiltering( string s )
   {
      string letters = GetFirstLetters( CamelSplit( s ) );
      if( letters.Length <= 1 || letters.Contains( "<" ) ) return null;
      return letters;
   }
```

Comment: I think you could try lucene.net in your project:

http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms